# Read only file instances of an ontology model in Jena

Tags: java, jena, ontology

I am reading an ontology with Jena Framework. I have a file that contains the instances and an import to an ontology (which I have in another file). This ontology has several instances but I'd like to read in the model only the instances contained in my instances file, not the instances in the ontology file.

I found this method:

```
Model base = myOntModel.getBaseModel();
```

But this method returns everything in the OntModel... Are there any way to do it? For example, reading the full model and then removing the instances that I don't want? Alternatively, is there any way to differentiate in the model between the instances of the ontology and those that are not in the ontology?

Comment: I just noticed your edit;  what do you mean that “[`getBaseModel`] returns everything in the OntModel”?  If you have an ontology O1 that imports an ontology O2, then when you read O1 into OntModel OM1, the result is that OM1's base model will have the triples from O1, and a submodel of OM1 will have the triples from O2.  `getBaseModel` returns the base model that contains just the triples from O1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attached is a JUnit test case demonstrating the segregation of OntModels their sub models, and their imports. Demonstrated is the ability to print/query only the content of the import model separate from the document which imports it. The assertions in the JUnit test case demonstrate differentiating between statements that are in the import, verses statements that are in the actual ontology.

Note that if you do not call model.getBaseModel().contains(...) instead of model.contains(...), then you will see the union of the base model and all sub models. Imports are constructed as sub models (as mentioned by Joshua Taylor)

```
@Test
public final void test() {
    // Create a doc manager / modelspec to resolve imports
    final OntDocumentManager docManager = new OntDocumentManager();
    final OntModelSpec modelSpec = new OntModelSpec(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);
    modelSpec.setDocumentManager(docManager);

    // Create an imported model that can be referenced by the docManager
    final OntModel imprt = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(modelSpec);
    docManager.addModel("x-model://a", imprt);

    // Populate imported model with some content
    final Ontology imprtOnt = imprt.createOntology("x-model://a");
    final OntClass clazz = imprt.createClass("x-model://a/class");
    assertTrue("delcared class should exist in a", imprt.contains(clazz, RDF.type, OWL.Class));

    System.out.println("x-model://a before");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
    imprt.write(System.out, "N3");
    System.out.println("\n");

    // Create a model which imports x-model://a
    final OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(modelSpec);
    model.setDynamicImports(true);
    final Ontology modelOnt = model.createOntology("x-model://b");
    modelOnt.addImport(imprtOnt);

    assertTrue("import b->a does not exist", model.hasLoadedImport("x-model://a"));
    assertTrue("triples in a should be acessible through b", model.contains(clazz, RDF.type, OWL.Class));
    assertFalse("triples in a should not be acessible through b's baseModel", model.getBaseModel().contains(clazz, RDF.type, OWL.Class));

    // Populate this new model
    final Individual ind = model.createIndividual("x-model://b/individual", clazz);
    assertTrue("delcared individual should exist in b", model.contains(ind, RDF.type, clazz));

    System.out.println("x-model://a after");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
    imprt.write(System.out, "N3");
    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println("x-model://b");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
    model.write(System.out, "N3");
}
```

Below is the sample output from the three calls to write the model. Note that x-model://b never contains any triples from x-model://a. The default behavior of write is to only consult the base model. To write all sub-models as well, you would utilize writeAll(...).

```
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<x-model://a/class>
      a       owl:Class .

<x-model://a>
      a       owl:Ontology .


x-model://a after
-------------------------------------------
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<x-model://a/class>
      a       owl:Class .

<x-model://a>
      a       owl:Ontology .


x-model://b
-------------------------------------------
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<x-model://b/individual>
      a       <x-model://a/class> .

<x-model://b>
      a       owl:Ontology ;
      owl:imports <x-model://a> .
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Before loading the Instances Ontology

If you read your Model, but don't process the imports, you won't see any instances that are declared in the imported ontology.  You'll still have the ontology object corresponding to your ontology, and you'll still have the triple

```
yourOntology owl:imports importedOntology
```

but you won't have the triples from `importedOntology`.  It seems like a call to [OntModel.setDynamicImports](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#setDynamicImports%28boolean%29) (with `false`, of course) before calling reading your file should ensure that you don't process those imports.

#### After loading the Instances Ontology

If for some reason you cannot *prevent* the OntModel from loading the imports (and thus making them visible from the instances ontology), you can take advantage of the way that Jena stores an ontologies imports as submodels of an OntModel.  You can examine the submodels of an OntModel using [OntModel.listSubModels](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#listSubModels%28boolean%29).  When you've identified the one that is there because of the `owl:imports` statement, you can use [OntModel.removeSubModel](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#removeSubModel%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model,%20boolean%29) to remove it from the OntModel.

#### Checking whether instances are in the BaseModel

If for some reason neither of the two approaches above work for you (but I'm pretty sure that at least one of them should), and you're still interested in the question

> is there any way to differentiate in the model between the instances of the ontology and those that are not in the ontology?

the answer is “yes, you can do that.”  There are two methods, [OntModel.isInBaseModel(Statement)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#isInBaseModel%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Statement%29) and [OntModel.isInBaseModel(RDFNode)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#isInBaseModel%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode%29) that will tell you whether a given Statement or RDFNode appear in the base model.  Of course, something could appear in *both*, so even though `isInBaseModel(someIndividual)` is true for `someIndividual`, it doesn't necessarily mean that `someIndividual` was *declared* in the instances ontology;  it could have been declared in the imported ontology, but also *mentioned* in the importing ontology.